# Mediatek MT3333AV doesn't start

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, gps, bga

Recently I started a project with an MT3333AV GPS IC. I desoldered the chip from the L86 GPS module and put it into my project.

After many tries I still can't start the IC. There is no 1.1 V going into the IC core. I have 1.8 V from an internal buck regulator, 2.8 V from a TLDO, and 1.1 V from an RTC LDO, however, there is no CLDO 1.1 V regulator (DVDD11_CORE1 and DVDD11_CORE2). This seems weird since on TCXO control pin I have 1.8 V which indicates that 1.8 V goes into CLDO.

Looking at the internal connections of the IC it can be seen that TCXO switch changes source between 1.8 V (CLDO) and 2.8 V (TLDO). Did I mess up something with the connections? Is it possible that during desoldering the CLDO could fail from heat? Can the chip somehow be locked and protected from desoldering?

[image: Datasheet power schematic and internal connections]

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: @out0f0rder unfortunately not, I tried many mediatek chips but none of them worked. If the schematic is correct then maybe there is a problem with soldering etc.

Comment: @kronikary I suppose there is something wrong with the schematic; at least I have a serious doubt DCV_FB should be connected that way. Unfortunately I was unable to find any hardware related docs. This datasheet you mentioned is pretty short and gave no solutions. BTW, I tried to request docs from Airoha, but got no answer. Looks like the best solution would be dropping the MT3333 and switch to using an IC of another vendor.